# Remove apps from Kids Category?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I recently got some of my kids app rejected because I use the share function. The rejection reason is:

"Apps in the Kids Category must get parental permission or use a parental gate before allowing the user to link out of the app or engage in commerce"

These apps have all been accepted before, so the restrictions of not allowing sharing must be new. As far as I can tell, there is no parental gate API for sharing? But removing the share button will make the app a lot less interesting!

Is there a way to get around this, or remove my app from Kids Category?

Answer (score 2):

Parental Gate rejection is applied when an application is targeted to kids section and it has a provision to redirect the user out of the application or it lets user engage in any sort of in commerce process.

You can actually add a parental control in your application for example on share button action, display a view with a simple mathematic operation (eg: 5x7), if the user answers correctly then, proceed normally. This way you can by pass the Parental Gate rejection.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/parental-gates/) is the important link for reference.

Comment: Thanks. Doing a Math question every time when wanted to send a picture to friend is just really a pain in the neck, especially when the app is targeted towards older kids. Is there a known way to remove the app from Kids Category?